# Backbone.js: Simpler save success handle

Tags: php, javascript, json, backbone.js

I've primarly searched this issue on **StackOverflow** however all of the answers seem to be too complex. I was merely looking for a simple solution.

```
urlToAdd.set({url: urlBody.value, tags:tagsToAdd});
urlToAdd.save({
success: function()
    {
       console.log("Success");
    }
});
```

This code is the im using inside a URLView which gets the given values from textboxes correctly and later on saving. However the issue is that I'm receiving an error at **validate** function. My validate function;

```
validate:function(attributes){
                if(attributes.tags[0].length<1)
                    return "You should create at least one tag";}
```

Validate helps to check if the arra assigned to **tags** parameter has more than one element. (I apply a differencet checking system I know but it does work if i don't put the **success** method. I'm using this method -not the array length - because even if the textbox is empty it still buts an element to array).

And my backend returns a string. I will later code it so it will return a json object. That will have a **msg** attribute saying "success". Is there any way I can capture my **php** page's result?

Comment: can you please make yourself clearer?

Comment: @ParthThakkar Which part you didn't understand?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have a bug in your validate function. If you want to check that `attributes.tags` has zero elements, you should be checking

```
if (attributes.tags.length < 1) { ...
```

*not* `attributes.tags[0].length`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However can you also help me to capture the response I get from the server? I

Comment: According to [backbone docs](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Model-save) you should not need to do that: `If a server-side validation fails, return a non-200 HTTP response code, along with an error response in text or JSON.`

Comment: But what if I would like to alert something to the user like 'your url has been succesfully inserted'?

Comment: From the same doc: `save accepts success and error callbacks in the options hash, which are passed (model, response) as arguments`. So you can simply pass a `success` callback to the save method, as in the code in your post, although backbone might expect it in the options hash in the second parameter to the method. Like `urlToAdd.save({}, {success: ...});`

Comment: Can I do like **{success: function(){ //stuff I will code }}**